# How do I get Kafka Manager Installed without external network access?

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am trying to get Kafka Manager installed on a cloud network that has no external access. I've downloaded all the dependent packages, but when SBT tries to run, it seems like it is attempting to download a bunch of jar files. The first thing it tries is to download:

```
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.9/sbt-launch.jar
```

I get a message saying it failed and to manually install it, which I did.  But again, apparently there are several dozen other jar files it needs externally.  Is there any way to install Kafka manager in an isolated network?

Comment: Can you provide the error trace?

Comment: Typically, such isolated networks need a Maven Central mirror for any Java code to build